# Linq using Include with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which returns me some dates, as well as an Id which related to a specific row in a table.

Basically, I am getting a list of all scheduled transactions for all accounts within an account portfolio.

The stored procedure returns a row with an Id (for the scheduled transaction), and some dates which I have minded within the proc.

If my query began with:

```
from p in Context.scheduled_transactions
```

then this plan would have worked. But I don't want to get the items like that, because in the proc, I am doing a lot of work to create business dates etc. So, instead of bring back the EF model - my proc just brings back the ID. I was HOPING to do something like this:

```
var trans = (from p in Context.get_scheduled_payments_by_portfolio(portfolioId)
                                          .Include("account")
                                          .Include("cost_centre")
                                          .Include("z_account_transaction_type")
                                          .Include("z_payment_frequency_type")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category.transaction_category")
                                          .Include("third_party")
                         select p).ToList();
```

But, the EF can't use 'Include' as it doesn't know what I am bring back. Although the id is called 'scheduled_transaction_id' in the proc - EF doesn't know that (understandably).

Is there a way I can tell EF that the ID is for a scheduled_transaction_model - and then use the 'Include'?

Maybe I need to just call the proc, which returns me a list of my objects, which has the scheduled_transaction_id, and all the dates I calculated in the proc, and then somehow, use that List<> in another linq query that can join the other tables?

EDIT:
I might be onto something! This doesn't show a syntax error. Just need to create a new Type... Playing with this:

```
var trans = (from p in Context.get_scheduled_payments_by_portfolio(portfolioId)
                         join st in Context.scheduled_transaction 
                                          .Include("account")
                                          .Include("cost_centre")
                                          .Include("z_account_transaction_type")
                                          .Include("z_payment_frequency_type")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category.transaction_category")
                                          .Include("third_party")
                                          on p.scheduled_transaction_id equals st.id 
                         select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Your last phrase is more suitable to solve your issue.

Comment: I am looking at that, and playing with this, but ... still not happy with the 'include': from p in Context.get_scheduled_payments_by_portfolio(portfolioId)
                         join st in Context.scheduled_transaction on p.scheduled_transaction_id  equals st.id 
                                          .Include("account")

Comment: You could create a table-valued function that returns `scheduled_transaction` objects. You can directly `Include` on the results of this function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = Context.get_scheduled_payments_by_portfolio(portfolioId).ToList();

var trans = (from p in Context.scheduled_transaction 
                  .Include("account")
                  .Include("cost_centre")
                  .Include("z_account_transaction_type")
                  .Include("z_payment_frequency_type")
                  .Include("transaction_sub_category")
                  .Include("transaction_sub_category.transaction_category")
                  .Include("third_party")
            where ids.Contains(p.id)
            select p).ToList();
```

Try Contains() method which will translated into SQL's IN(,,) statement.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, `join` the proc to the table I was using, and then I can use the `.Include()`

```
var trans = (from p in Context.get_scheduled_payments_by_portfolio(portfolioId)
                         join st in Context.scheduled_transaction 
                                          .Include("account")
                                          .Include("cost_centre")
                                          .Include("z_account_transaction_type")
                                          .Include("z_payment_frequency_type")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category")
                                          .Include("transaction_sub_category.transaction_category")
                                          .Include("third_party")
                                          on p.scheduled_transaction_id equals st.id 
                         select new {st, p}).ToList();
```

And then with the new type, I can itterate through the list, and build my objects.